# Cannot Compile My Program or Identify the Issue Here

Tags: c, gcc, cmake, clion

I can reckon that these "Global" arrays are problematic in some way,
but I just can't put my finger on what the issue is exactly.

car.h:

```
#ifendf ...
#define ...

#define N 10000

typedef struct car { <some code here> } Car;

extern Car carList[N];

<function declarations here>

#endif
```

car.c:

```
#include "car.h"

<function definitions here>
```

client.h:

```
#ifendf ...
#define ...

#define M 8000

typedef struct client { <some code here> } Client;

extern Client clientList[M];

<function declarations here>

#endif
```

client.c:

```
#include "car.h"
#include "client.h"

<function definitions here>
```

supplier.h:

```
#ifendf ...
#define ...

#define K 50

typedef struct supplier { <some code here> } Supplier;

extern Supplier supplierList[K];

<function declarations here>

#endif
```

supplier.c:

```
#include "supplier.h"

<function definitions here>
```

compiler message: (CLion IDE with GCC)

```
...
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/main.c.o:main.c:(.rdata$.refptr.supplierList[.refptr.supplierList]+0x0): undefined reference to `supplierList'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/main.c.o:main.c:(.rdata$.refptr.clientList[.refptr.clientList]+0x0): undefined reference to `clientList'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/main.c.o:main.c:(.rdata$.refptr.carList[.refptr.carList]+0x0): undefined reference to `carList'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
...
```

Comment: Each of your global arrays needs to be defined in one of your .c files.

Comment: I tried to search your code for occurrences of `supplierList` but I cannot search images for text. Please no images if code.

Comment: Hellmar-
how can I define these arrays?
They are empty and I'm not allowed to use malloc

Answer (score 0):

> undefined reference to `carList'

The error says that the linker doesn't find any object file with carList (and others).
You defined carList with the `extern` keyword, this tells the compiler that the actual data is in another file but you don't provide any.

To defines those array, you need a line without the `extern` keyword in [only] one of the source files.

Comment: "To defines those array, you need a line **with** the `extern` keyword" - You probably mean "... **without** the `extern` keyword: that keyword always means *declaration*, not *definition*.